# In my following HTML & CSS, How to place the elements with class names 'skill-1' & 'skill-2' inline and centered?

Tags: html, css

I'm Suramuthu, a user. I edited the question as it asked to improve the question. I have written a detailed answer for this question. Please keep the question opened so that I can post my answer

HTML & CSS CODE

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
}



.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
}

.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2% 1%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #f3ca20;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.125em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000000;
}

.skills {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}

.skill-1 {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    width: 25%;
    height: 53%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.skill-1:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    transition: 0.35s;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.skill-1 img {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 12%;
}

.skill-2 {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    width: 25%;
    height: 53%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.skill-2:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    transition: 0.35s;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.skill-2 img {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 12%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Ari's Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/home/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="active">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <h1>My Skills</h1>

      <!-- Skills -->
      <div class="skills">
        <!--Skill 1 -->
        <div class="skill-1">
          <img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/HTML5_Badge.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="skill-2">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/CSS3_logo.svg">
      </div>
    </div>  
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me I have tried so much and nothing is working. It looks like this [Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsiAw.png).

Comment: Please consider actually adding more details rather than entering dummy text. What do you mean by 'move my skills inline`. Also provide what you have tried, and what isn't working. You could also consider moving you code into a snippet to help outline your issue and make it easier for others to help. As an aside, it typically doesn't reflect well for your question if you skirt the system rules, users here tend to be sticklers about the rules (rightfully so).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I vertically center a div element for all browsers using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-can-i-vertically-center-a-div-element-for-all-browsers-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to display the skills.

```css
.skills {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.skill {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.skill img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;  
  width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.0625em;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2% 1%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #f3ca20;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.125em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
}

.skills {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.skill {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.skill:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transition: 0.35s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.skill img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/home/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="active">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1>My Skills</h1>

  <div class="skills">
    <div class="skill">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/HTML5_Badge.svg" alt="HTML5">
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/CSS3_logo.svg" alt="CSS3">
    </div>
  </div>  
</main>
```

If you want to center the skills vertically in the available viewport space, this can be achieved with a few more declarations.

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.skills {
  margin-block: auto;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;  
  width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.0625em;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2% 1%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #f3ca20;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.125em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
}

html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.skills {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-block: auto;
}

.skill {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.skill:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transition: 0.35s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.skill img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/home/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="active">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1>My Skills</h1>

  <div class="skills">
    <div class="skill">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/HTML5_Badge.svg" alt="HTML5">
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/CSS3_logo.svg" alt="CSS3">
    </div>
  </div>  
</main>
```

I must also suggest that you learn about [Document and website structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure). The navigation bar should be separate from the main content and therefore not inside the [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) element. The navigation bar should also be inside a [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) element. I also suggest using Flexbox for the navigation items instead of changing the display to inline.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html,
body,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 800;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #f3ca20;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.125em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000000;
}

.skills {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-block: auto;
}

.skill {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.skill:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transition: 0.35s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.skill img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <!-- Top Navigation Bar -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/home/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="active">Skills</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <h1>My Skills</h1>

  <section class="skills">
    <div class="skill">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/HTML5_Badge.svg" alt="HTML5">
    </div>
    <div class="skill">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/CSS3_logo.svg" alt="CSS3">
    </div>
  </section>  
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to center align those divs. Try this -

```
.skills {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```